# Blender 2.6 Node Editor Output Multiple Images At a Time

Tags: blender

I am trying to output multiple images in Blender at a time.

I have a scene and for example two cameras. I want to use two "file output" node in the node editor to do that. But it only outputs one image at a time. The other "file output" node will never work. And I can't find anywhere to change the name of the output images either.

Is it the limit of blender, or is there any way to do these? Thanks!

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render multiple cameras at once, you'll need to do a little bit of prep.

Duplicate your scene, linking objects. In the new scene, set your 2nd camera as active (Ctrl+Num0 while 2nd cam is selected).

In composite node editor, use 2 render layers, one for each scene. Select your File Output node and press 'n' to reveal the properties panel if not open already. Under Active Node in properties panel, click 'Add Input.' (In that same area you can name the output files as you wish.)

Link the 2 render layers w/ appropriate scenes to the 2 inputs on the File Output node.

You may need to remove any Render Layers from original scene, I'm not sure. Here's a sample:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/b76qaxdo89tnhyb/2013-04-02%2019_59_49-Blender.png

And what it outputs:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/597evwmdyynhu0z/2013-04-02%2020_00_10-MEDIA%20%28M_%29.png